# QuakeLive alternative on Linux

Tags: linux, game

Requirements

- Easy to install on Fedora (RPM) or installer
- Multiplayer with online players available
- Low hardware requirements - should work on Intel Gfx like QuakeLive
- Similar game style is nice to have

I'm asking because [QuakeLive is not available on Linux anymore](http://www.quakelive.com/#!news/site_news/34313).

Comment: As this is a game request, is this on-topic? There's an ongoing [meta discussion](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/51/would-video-game-related-question-be-ontopic) about game questions.

Comment: This question is off-topic as it is not looking for a solution to a problem. We have defined in various meta discussions that "killing boredom" is not a problem we are able to solve. The main reason to this is that this question can't have a definite answer.

Answer (score 8):

I had a lot of fun playing [Sauerbraten (Cube 2)](http://sauerbraten.org/). Its gratis and open source together with the server.

The graphics are good, the controls fluent. I never installed the server part but the client part was very intuitive so I suspect the server to be as well.

I played the game ~2005 on a regular (i.E. not gaming optimized) computer so it can most likely run on your hardware as well.

The game is a classical First Person Shooter for multiplayer. It has a Single Player Mode, but I always felt it more like a tutorial.

Some screenshots from their website:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]

Answer (score 4):

`su -c "yum install openarena"`

When I was playing FPS, I used to enjoy [OpenArena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenArena) a lot.

- It was designed to be very similar to Quake III Arena (which in turn is very close to Quake Live)
- I personally could feel sensations pretty close to the ones I had in Quake III Arena (whose game play is in turn very close to Quake Live)
- It is also available from the default repositories of a number of Linux distributions, including Fedora.
- The game was released a decade ago so it should be okay with your hardware

[image]

[image]

More on System Requirements:
http://openarena.wikia.com/wiki/LinuxInstall#Linux

> System Requirements
>
> - Minimum
> - Pentium II 233MHz / AMD K6-2 300MHz or equally powerful processor
> - 64MB of system memory
> - OpenGL supported video card with 16MB of video memory. (Voodoo Banshee, TNT and up) 300MB of hard drive space
>
> In theory, the game can run on any Pentium-class processor with a
>   Voodoo2, but don't expect much performance over 20fps and expect
>   loading time to be over a minute.
>
> You must have accelerated drivers for your video card installed for
>   best results. This may require using the not-entirely-open-source
>   NVIDIA drivers for NVIDIA cards. This also means that some video cards
>   may not work even if they meet the above-stated minimum requirements.